# Add points (x,y) to a d3 multi-line graph with time scale x-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

I'm currently attempting to build a a multi-line graph with a `d3.time.scale()` for the x-axis.

I'm trying to add circles to each point on lines of the graph, but have been unsuccessful thus far.

When I do something like:

`.attr('cx', function(d){ return x(d.price) })`

I get a negative number.

I was thinking of setting up another `scale (pointsScale)` to handle this but have been largely unsuccessful.

What am I doing wrong?

Please refer to my [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qamaroxuju/edit?html,css,output) for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into a few issues here:

- Since you made the x-axis a time-scale, I'm guessing that you actually want price to be the y variable, while date is the x variable. That's why `x(d.price)` is negative - d3 is trying to interpret the prices as dates, which doesn't end up making much sense. So replace your line of code above with this: `.attr('cy', function(d){ return y(d.price) })`
- In order to actually have circles be visible, they need to have three parameters set: `cx`, `cy`, and `r`. Since d3 already knows that your x axis is a time scale, you can set `cx` with `.attr('cx', function(d){ return x(d.date) })`. You can make `r` be whatever radius you want for the circles. Just choose one, or it will default to 0 and you won't be able to see the circles. `.attr('r', 4)`, for instance, would set the radius to a perfectly visible value of 4.
- You're drawing the circles before you draw the lines. As a result, the lines get drawn over the circles and it looks kind of weird. So move the circle code to after the line code if you want to avoid that.

Putting it all together, this is roughly what the code to create your circles should look like, and it should go after you declare `var paths`:

```
    var circles = company.selectAll('circle')
      .data(function(d){ return d.values; })
      .enter().append('circle')
      .attr('cy', function(d){
        return y(d.price);}) //Price is the y variable, not the x
      .attr('cx', function(d){
        return x(d.date);}) //You also need an x variable
      .attr('r',4); //And a radius - otherwise your circles have
                    //radius 0 and you can't see them!
```

Updated jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/gorukojoxu/edit?html,console,output

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense, I guess I was staring at the screen far too long yesterday. Any idea how to make the dots correlate to the same color as the path per chance?

Comment: If you're not going to have a ridiculous number of companies in your dataset, the simplest thing to do is probably just give each one of them a color attribute and call that.

Comment: I just did some hacky `d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode).datum().color`. It works for the moment. Thanks again for the help.